# IntelliJ with SBT plugin: Error Resolving [com.mycompany.mypackage]

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, build, sbt

I am trying to build a SBT based Scala project. The project has dependencies on packages on my company's local maven server. From within the company's network, I was able to compile/package(from cli and IntelliJ) the project successfully yesterday.

Today from home from command prompt, When I do:

```
sbt assembly
```

to build the repo it **works fine**.

But when I build from IntelliJ or do:

```
sbt compile|package
```

It is hitting the maven server and failing. My question is if the packages are already in the cache - `~/.ivy2/` then why maven server is hit. **Is there a way to avoid server hit**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a little search, found the answer

```
$ sbt "set offline := true" run
```